# Get PE and VA of executable file with C

Tags: c, executable

I want to write a little program in C to extract the PE (Entry Point) and VA (Virtual Address) of a COFF executable. How can I do that?

Comment: PE? VA? You need to be more precise on this.

Comment: What's a PE and a VE or a VA?

Comment: Virtual Adress and Entry Point, sorry (I've edited) .

Comment: What format is the binary? ELF? COFF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the fields you want are in the **Optional Header** (optional in that it doesn't appear in object files -- it's required in images). The first bytes in the file are the DOS stub, but at 0x3c you'll find the offset of the PE signature. Go there and you'll find the PE signature (`PE\0\0`). Immediately after that is the file header, which is 0x14 bytes long, and after that is the optional header. `AddressOfEntryPoint` is 0x10 bytes into the optional header and spans four bytes, and `BaseOfCode` is right after it at 0x14 (also 4 bytes).

So, in short:

- Pull the PE signature offset from 0x3c
- Read 4 bytes starting at `(PE signature offset)+0x28` -- this is the `AddressOfEntryPoint`
- Read 4 bytes starting at `(PE signature offset)+0x2c` -- this is the `BaseOfCode`

Remember to deal with endianness if necessary

Comment: Hum ok, and which function can help me to do that? Thanks :)

Comment: @Pierre Er. You just open the file, seek to certain addresses, and read. I guess `fopen`, `fseek`, and `fread`, if that's what you're asking

Comment: @MM Ok I wasn't aware of the fseek function existence . Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

http://pastebin.com/LTN6VjJE

```
/*


                    Program to dump the PE,DOS headers and Hex Dump of particular section
                                                                        Sat 03/24/2007
                                                                            by
                                                                    K.Vineel Kumar Reddy
                                                                        In VC++ 6.0


                    ref : http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/PECOFF.mspx
                    tools used : Hiew



                  BRIEF VIEW OF PE FILE

                .----------------------.
                |                      |
                |    Other stuff not   |
                |    touched in this   |
                |    program           |
                |                      |
                |----------------------|
                |                      |
                | Various Section like |
                |        .....         |
                |        .....         |
        .------>|       .reloc         |
        | .---->|       .idata         |
        | | .-->|       .data          |
        | | | .>|       .text          |
        | | | | |----------------------|
        '-|-|-|-|                      | <--- Each entry in section table have pointer
          '-|-|-|         Section      |      offsets to actual sections
            '-|-|     Header or Table  |
              '-|                      |      ---.----------------.
                |----------------------|-----/   |   PE Optional  |  1) ImageBase
                |                      |         |    Header      |
                |                      |         |                |
                |        NT Headers    |         |----------------|
                |                      |         |     COFF/PE    |  1) NumberOfSections
                |                      |         |   Header Info  |  2) SizeOfOptionalHeader
                |----------------------|-----    |----------------|
                |         UNUSED       |     \   |   PE Signature |
                |----------------------|      ---'----------------'
                |      MS-DOS stub     |
                |----------------------|
                |         UNUSED       |
                |----------------------|
                |     MS-DOS Header    | <-- Here at 0x3c location we have the offset of NT Header
                '----------------------'


Structres related to these exe headers
--------------------------------------
1)   MS-DOS Header   ---> IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
2)   NT Header       ---> IMAGE_NT_HEADERS --->contain 
                                           --->IMAGE_FILE_HEADER dealing with COFF/PE Header
                                           --->IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER dealing with Optional PE Header

3)   Section Table   ---> IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER

Key Points 
----------

  dosHeader = Memory mapped base address
  ntHeader = (IMAGE_NT_HEADER)((DWORD)dosHeader + dosHeader->e_lfanew)
  sectionHeader = (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((DWORD)ntHeader + OFFSET(OptionalHeader) + sizeof(OptionalHeader)) 
  each section = (char *)((DWORD)dosHeader + sectionHeader.PointerToRawData)


                                                                        ASCII ART by
                                                                         Vineel :)

*/









#include<stdio.h> 
#include<windows.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<tchar.h>

void Help()
{
    printf("\nUsage \ntest <path to exe file> [ -h <section> ]\n");
}
void HexDump(char * p ,int size,int secAddress)
{
    int i=1,temp=0;
    wchar_t buf[18];      //Buffer  to store the character dump displayed at the right side 
    printf("\n\n%x: |",secAddress);

    buf[temp]    = ' ' ;  //initial space
    buf[temp+16] = ' ' ;  //final space 
    buf[temp+17] =  0  ;  //End of buf
    temp++;               //temp = 1;
    for( ; i <= size ; i++, p++,temp++)
    {
        buf[temp] = !iswcntrl((*p)&0xff)? (*p)&0xff :'.';
        printf("%-3.2x",(*p)&0xff );

        if(i%16 == 0){    //print the chracter dump to the right    
            _putws(buf);
            if(i+1<=size)printf("%x: ",secAddress+=16);
            temp=0;
        }
        if(i%4==0)printf("|");
    }
    if(i%16!=0){
        buf[temp]=0;
        for(;i%16!=0;i++)
            printf("%-3.2c",' ');
        _putws(buf);
    }
}

main(int argc , char ** argv){

    int i=0;
    HANDLE hMapObject,hFile;            //File Mapping Object
    LPVOID lpBase;                      //Pointer to the base memory of mapped file
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;        //Pointer to DOS Header
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeader;         //Pointer to NT Header
    IMAGE_FILE_HEADER header;           //Pointer to image file header of NT Header 
    IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER opHeader;     //Optional Header of PE files present in NT Header structure
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pSecHeader;   //Section Header or Section Table Header
    if(argc>1){

        //Open the Exe File 
        hFile = CreateFile(argv[1],GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
        if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){printf("\nERROR : Could not open the file specified\n"); goto info;};

        //Mapping Given EXE file to Memory
        hMapObject = CreateFileMapping(hFile,NULL,PAGE_READONLY,0,0,NULL);
        lpBase = MapViewOfFile(hMapObject,FILE_MAP_READ,0,0,0);

        //Get the DOS Header Base 
        dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpBase;// 0x04000000

        //Check for Valid DOS file
        if(dosHeader->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE){
            //Dump the Dos Header info
            printf("\nValid Dos Exe File\n------------------\n");
            printf("\nDumping DOS Header Info....\n---------------------------");
            printf("\n%-36s%s ","Magic number : ",dosHeader->e_magic==0x5a4d?"MZ(Mark Zbikowski)":"-");
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Bytes on last page of file :",dosHeader->e_cblp);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Pages in file : ",dosHeader->e_cp);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Relocation : ",dosHeader->e_crlc);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Size of header in paragraphs : ",dosHeader->e_cparhdr);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Minimum extra paragraphs needed : ",dosHeader->e_minalloc);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Maximum extra paragraphs needed : ",dosHeader->e_maxalloc);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Initial (relative) SS value : ",dosHeader->e_ss);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Initial SP value : ",dosHeader->e_sp);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Checksum : ",dosHeader->e_csum);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Initial IP value : ",dosHeader->e_ip);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Initial (relative) CS value : ",dosHeader->e_cs);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","File address of relocation table : ",dosHeader->e_lfarlc);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Overlay number : ",dosHeader->e_ovno);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","OEM identifier : ",dosHeader->e_oemid);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","OEM information(e_oemid specific) :",dosHeader->e_oeminfo);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","RVA address of PE header : ",dosHeader->e_lfanew);
            printf("\n===============================================================================\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("\nGiven File is not a valid DOS file\n");
            goto end;
        }

        //Offset of NT Header is found at 0x3c location in DOS header specified by e_lfanew
        //Get the Base of NT Header(PE Header)  = dosHeader + RVA address of PE header
        ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)(dosHeader) + (dosHeader->e_lfanew));
        //Identify for valid PE file  
        if(ntHeader->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE){
            printf("\nValid PE file \n-------------\n");

            //Dump NT Header Info....
            printf("\nDumping COFF/PE Header Info....\n--------------------------------");
            printf("\n%-36s%s","Signature :","PE");


            //Get the IMAGE FILE HEADER Structure
            header = ntHeader->FileHeader;

            //Determine Machine Architechture
            printf("\n%-36s","Machine Architechture :");
            switch(header.Machine){ //Only few are determined (for remaining refer to the above specification)
            case 0x0:    printf("All "); break;
            case 0x14d:  printf("Intel i860"); break;
            case 0x14c:  printf("Intel i386,i486,i586"); break;
            case 0x200:  printf("Intel Itanium processor"); break;
            case 0x8664: printf("AMD x64"); break;
            case 0x162:  printf("MIPS R3000"); break;
            case 0x166:  printf("MIPS R4000"); break;
            case 0x183:  printf("DEC Alpha AXP"); break;
            default:     printf("Not Found"); break;
            }
            //Determine the characteristics of the given file
            printf("\n%-36s","Characteristics : ");
            if((header.Characteristics&0x0002) == 0x0002) printf("Executable Image ,");
            if((header.Characteristics&0x0020) == 0x0020) printf("Application can address > 2GB ,");
            if((header.Characteristics&0x1000) == 0x1000) printf("System file (Kernel Mode Driver(I think)) ,");
            if((header.Characteristics&0x2000) == 0x2000) printf("Dll file ,");
            if((header.Characteristics&0x4000) == 0x4000) printf("Application runs only in Uniprocessor ,");


            printf("\n%-36s%s","Time Stamp :",ctime(&(header.TimeDateStamp)));          //Determine Time Stamp
            printf("%-36s%d","No.sections(size) :",header.NumberOfSections);            //Determine number of sections
            printf("\n%-36s%d","No.entries in symbol table :",header.NumberOfSymbols);
            printf("\n%-36s%d","Size of optional header :",header.SizeOfOptionalHeader);

            printf("\n\nDumping PE Optional Header Info....\n-----------------------------------");
            //Info about Optional Header
            opHeader = ntHeader->OptionalHeader;
            //printf("\n\nInfo of optional Header\n-----------------------");
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Address of Entry Point : ",opHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Base Address of the Image : ",opHeader.ImageBase);
            printf("\n%-36s%s","SubSystem type : ",
                opHeader.Subsystem==1?"Device Driver(Native windows Process)":
            opHeader.Subsystem==2?"Windows GUI":
            opHeader.Subsystem==3?"Windows CLI":
            opHeader.Subsystem==9?"Windows CE GUI":
            "Unknown"
                );
            printf("\n%-36s%s","Given file is a : ",opHeader.Magic==0x20b?"PE32+(64)":"PE32");
            printf("\n%-36s%d","Size of code segment(.text) : ",opHeader.SizeOfCode);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Base address of code segment(RVA) :",opHeader.BaseOfCode);
            printf("\n%-36s%d","Size of Initialized data : ",opHeader.SizeOfInitializedData);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Base address of data segment(RVA) :",opHeader.BaseOfData);
            printf("\n%-36s%#x","Section Alignment :",opHeader.SectionAlignment);
            printf("\n%-36s%d","Major Linker Version : ",opHeader.MajorLinkerVersion);
            printf("\n%-36s%d","Minor Linker Version : ",opHeader.MinorLinkerVersion);              



            printf("\n\nDumping Sections Header Info....\n--------------------------------");

            //Retrive a pointer to First Section Header(or Section Table Entry)


            for(pSecHeader = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(ntHeader),i=0;i<ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;i++,pSecHeader++){   
                printf("\n\nSection Info (%d of %d)",i+1,ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections);
                printf("\n---------------------");
                printf("\n%-36s%s","Section Header name : ", pSecHeader->Name);
                printf("\n%-36s%#x","ActualSize of code or data : ", pSecHeader->Misc.VirtualSize);
                printf("\n%-36s%#x","Virtual Address(RVA) :", pSecHeader->VirtualAddress);
                printf("\n%-36s%#x","Size of raw data (rounded to FA) : ", pSecHeader->SizeOfRawData);
                printf("\n%-36s%#x","Pointer to Raw Data : ", pSecHeader->PointerToRawData);
                printf("\n%-36s%#x","Pointer to Relocations : ", pSecHeader->PointerToRelocations);
                printf("\n%-36s%#x","Pointer to Line numbers : ", pSecHeader->PointerToLinenumbers);
                printf("\n%-36s%#x","Number of relocations : ", pSecHeader->NumberOfRelocations);
                printf("\n%-36s%#x","Number of line numbers : ", pSecHeader->NumberOfLinenumbers);
                printf("\n%-36s%s","Characteristics : ","Contains ");
                if((pSecHeader->Characteristics&0x20)==0x20)printf("executable code, ");
                if((pSecHeader->Characteristics&0x40)==0x40)printf("initialized data, ");
                if((pSecHeader->Characteristics&0x80)==0x80)printf("uninitialized data, ");
                if((pSecHeader->Characteristics&0x80)==0x80)printf("uninitialized data, ");
                if((pSecHeader->Characteristics&0x200)==0x200)printf("comments and linker commands, ");
                if((pSecHeader->Characteristics&0x10000000)==0x10000000)printf("shareable data(via DLLs), ");
                if((pSecHeader->Characteristics&0x40000000)==0x40000000)printf("Readable, ");
                if((pSecHeader->Characteristics&0x80000000)==0x80000000)printf("Writable, ");


                // If -h or /h option is given then provide HexDump
                if(argc==4&& (!strcmpi(argv[2],"-h")||!strcmpi(argv[2],"/h"))){
                    if(!strcmpi(argv[3],pSecHeader->Name))
                        if(pSecHeader->SizeOfRawData!=0)
                        HexDump((char *)((DWORD)dosHeader + pSecHeader->PointerToRawData) , pSecHeader->SizeOfRawData , opHeader.ImageBase + pSecHeader->VirtualAddress);
                }

            }


            printf("\n===============================================================================\n");
        }
        else goto end;

end:
        //UnMaping 
        UnmapViewOfFile(lpBase);
        CloseHandle(hMapObject);
    }
    else Help();
info:

    printf("\
            \
            \
                            This Program is written by\
                            K.Vineel Kumar Reddy.\
                                    III/IV IT\
                            Gayathri Vidya Parishad college of Eng.\
            \
            \
            ");
}
```

Please check the above program..............